# Question about new organization of ROS with catkin instead of rosbuild

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-groovy, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!!

My name is Ivan. I have worked some years with ROS. But now, I don´t Understand the new organization of package.
For example in Fuerte version, we had this arquitecture:
example-ros-pkg

 - RobotA(Stack)
- Package1
- Package2
- Package3

- RobotB(Stack)

  - Package1
  - Package2
  - Package3
- RobotD(Stack)
  .
  .
  .
- RobotE(Stack)
  .
  .
  .

  In a Groovy version, the stack concept has been removed, How can reorganize our repository to respect the new standard?

Thanks for your comments!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62406/question-about-new-organization-of-ros-with-catkin-instead-of-rosbuild/) by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2013-05-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The closest equivalent to the old *stack* concept is the new *metapackage*, as described [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/#Removal_of_Stacks).  A metapackage is a package that only contains references to other packages (no code), plus a special `<metapackage/>` tag.  This allows users to install a group of packages using a metapackage, just like they did previously with stacks.  Metapackages are also more flexible in that they allow you to group packages that may not be located in the same repository / filesystem.

A suggested layout is shown [here](http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild#Package_Layout_in_Workspace) for how to organize the metapackage / package hierarchy in groovy:

```
my_stack/        --> my_metapackage/
  my_package_1/  -->   my_package_1/
    manifest.xml -->     package.xml
  ...
  my_package_n/  -->   my_package_n/
    manifest.xml -->     package.xml
  stack.xml      -->   my_metapackage
                         package.xml (Internally, a tag indicates it's a metapackage)
```

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on 2013-05-09**:
Thanks a lot for you response Jeremy, Now see clearly the new organization, as I read the documentation and I not understood very well the concept